# Create Kendo UI grid columns from arrays in datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, datasource

So considering something like this being returned from my Kendo dataSource:

> {
>
> name:"johnny",
>
> age:"27",
>
> hobby:[
>
> ```
>  {
>     id:"1",
>     designation:"soccer",
>     score:2000
>  },
>  {
>     id:"2",
>     designation:"tennis",
>     score:1220
>  },
>  {
>     id:"3",
>     designation:"chess",
>     score:4440
>  }
> ```
>
> ]
>   }

How can i use the hobby field to create columns for each type?
I tried to use fetch method to get the data and then manually add the columns to the current ones but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you figure it out?